# Key differences between Mongodb and S3 for data storage scalability

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

What are the key differences in features, scalability, and use cases between Amazon S3 and MongoDB for data storage?

I'm considering using it to store large amounts of JSON documents with configuration information but would like to understand the key differences between both systems before progressing.